# Can someone please explain to me how I can bold text in a string with <b>?

Tags: android

[My string array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYYCo.png)

I cannot get this bold text to show up when playing the app. All I find is something about fromHtml(String). Can I use this with an array? If so, how?

Comment: please don't post images of code, include everything relevant to your question inside your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(String source, int flag);`

sample usage.

```
String source = "this will be <b>bold<b>"
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(source, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

reference [HtmlCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))